Developer console viewing issue
I do not see developer console on my interface from setting menu. Any particular settings that need to be done in my case? 

Do you/your profile have the appropriate permissions? You need API Enabled and View All Data

To open the developer console below user permission is needed:

To use the Developer Console:    API Enabled AND View All Data
To view, retain, and delete debug logs:  View All Data
To execute anonymous Apex:   Author Apex
To use code search and run SOQL or SOSL on the query tab:    API Enabled
To save changes to Apex classes and triggers:    Author Apex
To save changes to Visualforce pages and components:     Customize Application
To save changes to Lightning resources:  Customize Application

More details: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_opening.htm&type=5
